# Computed property getting called before prop initialization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

In my Vue app, I am getting an array from map getters and I am trying to filter this array based on type which is a prop in a computed property. I checked both of them, both are strings, but the filter is not working properly, since I feel the computed property is called before the prop is initialized with value. Need some help with this?

```
all: 'mdm/all', // here 'mdm' indicates module name and 'all' is the state

prop: [type]
```

Inside computed, I have a property called

```
getData() {
const filteredData = this.all.filter(ele => ele.type === this.type.toLowerCase());
return filteredData.map(item => (
 {name: item.name,
  orderNo: item.order_no
 });
}
```

In the above code, both `ele.type` and `this.type` seems to be strings with similar value (say 'expired') but the filteredData always happens to be an empty array.
Not sure what could be cause for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug what `.filter()` is doing with a console log inside of it, for example:

```js
this.all.filter(ele => { 
    console.log(`${ele.type} === ${this.type.toLowerCase()}?`, ele.type === this.type.toLowerCase());
    return ele.type === this.type.toLowerCase(); 
})`
```

which will print out the result of `ele.type === this.type.toLowerCase()` every loop so you can verify what exactly is happening.